# SQL Server query - find last order data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have history (no ongoing month data) table T1:

[image: picture 1]

*na - customer canceled services

There is a current (201706) table T2 (has data for ongoing month):

[image: picture 2]

How to write a Microsoft SQL Server query to find customer's aaaa latest order date of current service?

Answer: aaaa ordered 2 at 201706, bbb - 1 at 201705.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: What have you tried so far???  Post your query, then we'll help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customer,service from T1 
GROUP BY customer,service HAVING service >=1 
ORDER BY ordered DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to retrieve only 1 date per Customer:

```
SELECT
latest_date.Customer as Customer,
T1.Service as Service
FROM
    (SELECT 
        Customer as Customer,
        max(Ordered) as date
    FROM T1 GROUP BY Customer) latest_date
    LEFT JOIN T1
        ON  latest_date.date=T1.ordered
GROUP BY Customer,Service
```